# Why Scalacheck's Gen.pick adds a post-condition check?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am using custom `Gen` sequences because my requirement is 'pick a bunch of elements in collection C (named A), and then a subset of A (named B), then generate a bunch of stuff randomly using B.'

The moment i use a a collection C of large size (e.g. 10000), I end up with tests that take forever. The flame graph indicate that the time is spent in lambdas in the Scalacheck implementation. Looking at the code, I have a gut feeling that this code in `pick` is adding plenty of delay: `.suchThat(_.forall(x => l.exists(x == _)))`

This is a linear operation that can turn quadratic if the input collection doesn't have fast lookups like a `HashSet`.

My question is: why is that `suchThat` condition added in the first place? Can we have an 'unsafe' API without those?